# unable to select an one option from Kendo dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

As im a beginner to selenium, i want to select one option from kendo dropdown by selenium web driver so that i used explicitly wait, Javascript Executor and Actions.. but these are all not helping me to solve this problem

Here in dropdown by default the select option will be there, so i need to click that select option so that list of options will display in dropdown and again i need to choose the Cash option from the drop down

please anyone guide me to get this done

HTML Code:

```
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="ddlSettleMode-list" data-role="popup" style="position: absolute; height: 200px; display: none;"><span class="k-list-filter"><input class="k-textbox" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="ddlSettleMode_listbox" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-activedescendant="63c26b42-3507-49cb-83e6-1d37c206cb5f"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-search">select</span></span><div class="k-group-header" style="display:none"></div><div unselectable="on" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; height: 171px;"><ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="ddlSettleMode_listbox" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-focused k-state-selected" data-offset-index="0" id="63c26b42-3507-49cb-83e6-1d37c206cb5f" aria-selected="true">Select</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Cash</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Card</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="3">Cheque</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="4">Paytm</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="5">NEFT</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="6">DD</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="7">IMPS</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="8">Online</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="9">UPI</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="10">Wallet</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="11">Digital</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="12">CMS</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="13">Univ</li></ul></div></div>
```

This is my selenium code:

```
WebDriverWait Waita = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        Waita.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Select']")));
        Waita.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Select']"))).click();
        WebDriverWait Waitb = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        Waitb.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='k-item' and text()='Cash'][@data-offset-index='1']")));
        Waitb.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='k-item' and text()='Cash'][@data-offset-index='1']"))).click();
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //li[@class='k-item' and text()='Cash'][@data-offset-index='1'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Comment: You are using my proposed solution to your same previous question without providing any feedback/credits to my updated answer.

Comment: i replied for your comment in the previous question. pls check that

Comment: I used your solutions but its not working for me. im unable to understand whats wrong with my selenium code